Postgres unique key contraint on updating multiple rows
I have a table with an id,name,order_index.
The order_index must be unique, therefore a unique constraint is defined.
Lets say it is stored
id,name,order_index
1 ,'a',1
2 ,'b',2
3 ,'c',3

and then a new order must be saved:
id:1 gets order_index 2.
id:2 gets order_index 1.
Then a foreign key violation happens.
It would be possible to have an intermediate query to set an order_index to e.g. 4. But is there a more convenient solution for that?

I don't see how to solve a foreign key violation without knowing where said foreign key is. Please share the definition of your table(s), the query you are attempting to run and the exact error message you get.

@Atmo: I think he meant unique key violation. Sigurd you should correct that...

It kind of proves my point... The question is not well-written enough people know what problem they are asked to help with.

One solution could be an after update (after all) trigger checking the uniqueness.
Then you could update multiple rows with a case expression on the id,
or a mapping table...
I'm not sure wether this is more convinient, but you'll have no in-between states...
